# do I need to add all of the javascript and css links in bundleconfig asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

In my project, I have a lot of javascript link and css link I don't know, can I add all of those in bundle-config? of course, this is for admin Area and also I have a user Area.

this is admin Area

```
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/js.cookie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/jquery.blockui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->
<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/morris/morris.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/morris/raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/counterup/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/counterup/jquery.counterup.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/amcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/serial.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/pie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/radar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/themes/light.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/themes/patterns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amcharts/themes/chalk.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/ammap/ammap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/ammap/maps/js/worldLow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/amcharts/amstockcharts/amstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/horizontal-timeline/horizontal-timeline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.categories.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/jquery-easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
<!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/scripts/app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- END THEME GLOBAL SCRIPTS -->
<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/pages/scripts/dashboard.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- END PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
<!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT SCRIPTS -->
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/layouts/layout2/scripts/layout.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-sidebar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/layouts/global/scripts/quick-nav.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: can I add all of those in bundle-config? Yes

Comment: Can you - Yes. Would you - Probably not - why load all of them into every view when its highly unlikely that they will be used in the view. You can create multiple bundles where you might group scripts that are likely to be used in all view, and other bundles that might be only used in certain views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add as many files to your bundles as you like, and it benefits you to do so as it reduces the number of requests the browser has to make to load your page.

For example:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/adminScripts").Include(
          "~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js",
          "~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/js.cookie.min.js"))
```

Then on your page:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/adminScripts")
```